# How keep dropdown bootstrap visible until click back the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using dropdown feature from bootstrap. I want the menu still visible until I click back the button back. It must look like a switch . If we want to see the list, we must click the button, and also to hide it back. And it still open although we click in the  outside and in the  inside of the list button .

```
   <h2>Click the dropdown button </h2>
   <p>It will stay open unless clicked again to close </p>

<div class="dropdown keep-open">
    <!-- Dropdown Button -->
    <button id="dLabel" role="button" href="#"
       data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" 
       class="btn btn-primary">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

<!-- Dropdown Menu -->
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" 
    aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to open and to close the dropdown menu , only from the button.

I [use](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZS4L7/) this, but still it hide the list when i click in the inside list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

> **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4L7/1639/)**

```
$('.keep-open #dLabel').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).parent().attr('closable', true );
  }
})
```

Click event is sent when the bootstrap is failed on `hide dropdown` with another call to `hide dropdown` as suggested by [author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6661759/mike-kane)

Just add this to your code